# write a background process to check process is still active

Tags: unix, shell, cron

In UNIX, I have a utility, say 'Test_Ex', a binary file. How can I write a job or a shell script(as a cron job) running always in the background which keeps checking if 'Test_Ex' is still running every 5 seconds(and probably hide this job). If it is running, do nothing. If not, delete a directory at the   specified path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script:

```
pgrep Test_Ex > /dev/null || rm -r dir
```

If you don't have `pgrep`, use

```
ps -e -ocomm | grep Test_Ex || ...
```

instead.

Comment: thanks.. the procedure is to edit crontab and add this line. Can this manual task be done using a shell script as part of an installation process?

Comment: @Abhi: Yes, just put that line in a script file. The first line of the file should be `#!/bin/sh` and that `pgrep...` command line should be wrapped in a loop like `while :; do pgrep ...; sleep 5; done` and then run the script in the background: `scriptname &`. You'll probably want to save the PID so you can kill it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Utilities like [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), originally part of the Ubuntu linux distribution I believe, are good for monitoring running tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to not do it.  If you want to know if Test_Ex is still running, then start it from a script that looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
Test_Ex
logger "Test_Ex died"
rm /p/a/t/h
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
while ! Test_ex
do
  logger "Test_Ex terminated unsuccesfully, restarting in 5 seconds"
  sleep 5
done
```

Querying ps regularly is a bad idea, and trying to monitor it from cron is a horrible, horrible idea.  There seems to be some comfort in the idea that crond will always be running, but you can no more rely on that than you can rely on the wrapper script staying alive; either one can be killed at any time.  Waking up every 10 seconds to query ps is just a waste of resources.